# How to check if NULL value exists in multidimesional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have seen some methods to determine if some value exists in php multidimensional array but I am stuck at simple problem.

I have a following array.

```
$data  = [
      ['name' => 'sagar', 'address' => 'kathmandu'],
      ['name' => 'sagar', 'address' => null ]
    ];
```

I want to check if null value exists anywhere inside 2 dimensional array and keys can be anything. Is there any builtin function or we have made our own or some methodology to check ?

If you have any idea, it would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$hasNull = false;
foreach ($data as $set) {
    if ($hasNull = in_array(null, $set, true)) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir, There can be more than 1000 records with 10 to 20 elements in each records. So, Will it be fast enough ?

Comment: @SagarGautam You can run this code and have benchmarks if you like for those 1000 records, but this is indeed the fastest way to check for NULLs

Comment: I will check this !

Comment: Well it stops looping as soon as it finds a null, so not all nested records will be evaluated. As for how long in total, I couldn't say for sure. I don't suspect it'd have too hard a time chewing on a thousand or so records, but even a more clever use of a native function like `array_map()` than what I could come up with would still be looping under the hood. You'd probably have to look into parallel processing to get any significant performance boost. Is there anything more about the circumstances we can look at to reduce the initial set?